# How long does it take to register different impacts in the Double-Slit Experiment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-eraser

Consider a Double-Slit Experiment with a lens between the slits and the screen. The lens focuses the interference patterns in such a way that **R01** + **R02** = **D0**. When a measuring device is put at one of the slits the interference pattern disappears and on the screen we can see **R03** + **R04** = **D0**.

Because of the lens there is no way to tell just by looking at the screen if it is a combination of the interference patterns or a combination of the lumps.

Frequency of impacts at positions:

[image]

What would a plot of the time taken to get to the screen at positions look like? Would it look the same for when there are lumps and when there is interference?

Comment: I don't understand all those graphs. I suppose people could figure them out if they put enough time into it. But if you want an answer, it would help to explain your question much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Photons always have their wave properties (and particle properties). If you want to observe the wave properties the double slit is a good experiment. (The single slit or a dichroic filter is another way to observe wave properties).

The small source, double slit and screen combine to constrain the path of the photons to a few visible choices .... the "interference pattern" shows bright areas where photons can go, the dark areas that have no photons.  Per Feynman " a photon considers all paths" and chooses "the most probable".  Or stated another way as .. every photon determines its own path.

In the QEE a source photon creates 2 entangled photons, the creation of the entangled pair will not occur unless both photons have a path. Per wikipedia "Thus, when a pair of entangled photons is created, but one of the two is blocked by a polarizer and lost, the remaining photon will be filtered out of the data set as if it was one of the many non-entangled photons. When viewed this way, it is not surprising that making changes to the upper path can have an impact to measurements taken on the lower path ...."

In general the QEE was said to allow information faster than the speed of light but this has been disproven.

In the top arm of the apparatus the detector D0 (per QEE diagram on wikipedia) detects both the interfered type photons as well as the regular (single slit like) photons.  In this arm photons take a similar path for both types, the time for this path is the same for both types.  In the bottom arm the path is 8ns longer (per wikipedia), it is in the lower arm where the photons interact with the first set of beam splitters (50/50 random chance) ... when they have the d3/d4 path, the partner (idler) photon shows no interference.  When the partner (idler) photon takes the d1/d2 path it has a choice of d1 or d2 ... thus interference.

Comment: There is a big problem with trying to time photons as they are generated by nature randomly.  Especially in single photon experiments, we can power up the source but the photon generates/emits when its good and ready, we can only time the impact on the sensor. But if we know the distance travel we can calculate the start time from t=d/c.

Comment: Your question is saying/asks if that the photon behaving as a wave or particle but a photon always has both properties.  We observe the wave nature when we set up the double slit path option i.e the "interference" pattern.  We observe the "lump" pattern when we mess with the photon or either of the entangled photons along the path i.e for entangled photons we are forcing one photon to be "measured" which affects the other.

Comment: Photon paths are determined in advance ... an excited electron in an atom is already generating forces in the EM field thru what are called virtual photons. Eventually the real photon is emitted.

Comment: So the timing is pretty much impossible to measure, but what would it look like if we could? What would the hypothetical timing look like for the lumps and for the interference?

Comment: If we could do it the timing is the same in both cases .... but knowing the path length traveled is also required.

Comment: if the timing is the same then the path length must also be the same right? Edit your answer to say these things and I'll mark it as answered.

Comment: See added paragraph. Hope that helps.